# How come for Integer arrays, as in Integer arr[] = new Integer[], you can't change their value, you can only set them?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I was doing a problem in Codeforces and had to use an Integer arr[] = new Integer[200001]. I wanted to store 200001 counters for their index values(for example, if I got 19 then arr[19] would be the number of 19s that appeared in the array). However, when I went to do arr[num]++ or arr[num] += 1, it would not work. Only when you set arr[num] to some number does it work. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: use int arr[] instead

Comment: If course you can change their value. Please post the full code youve tried.

Comment: If you want to get `arr[0] == 0`, `arr[1] == 1`, etc you'll need to write a for loop

Comment: What is num? What errors or unexpected behavior you get?

Comment: You probably get a `NullPointerException`, because the `Integer[]` array is initialized with `null` on every index. Either use an `int[]` array or fill the array after it has been created, e.g. using `java.util.Arrays.fill(arr, 0);`

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't work because you haven't initialized each element of the array, you just have an Integer array with null references.
you should first do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
}
```

The easiest way is to use an int array instead of an Integer array.

Comment: No he wants to use the values as a counter for the index